# Ionic 3: IonicPage can’t use/bind to custom components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Having a bit of a play around with Ionic 3's new [IonicPage](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/), which handles lazy loading and routing, but struggling to get to grips with importing custom components.

If I initialise a page, and it's corresponding module as per the docs (see below), I get an error stating that my page template cannot bind to the properties of my custom components.

**Error Output**:

> core.es5.js:1085 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'locations' since it isn't a known property of 'location-search-input'.
>   1. If 'location-search-input' is an Angular component and it has 'locations' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'location-search-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component

I simply reference my custom component in my markup as follows: 
`<location-search-input [locations]="searchLocations"></location-search-input>`, which worked perfectly well prior to upgrading to Ionic 3 and switching to the new `@IonicPage` decorators.

Just for clarity here's a snippet of my custom component, in which `locations` is declared as a property/input.

```
@Component({selector: 'location-search-input', templateUrl: './location-search-input.component.html'})

export class LocationSearchInput {

  @Input() locations: any[] = [];

  constructor(public navController: NavController, private googlePlacesService: GooglePlacesService) {
      }

}
```

I have a feeling I am perhaps supposed to declare/import my custom component in the page's Module, but then again I'm not sure. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Page Module** - *basic template (as per docs)*

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {IonicPageModule} from "ionic-angular";
import {BrowsePage} from "./browse.page";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [BrowsePage],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(BrowsePage),
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    BrowsePage,
  ]
})
export class BrowsePageModule {
}
```

Comment: `LocationSearchInput` is declared in app module?

Comment: @suraj, yes it is declared in the app module, and works on other pages that do not use the IonicPage declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [**doc (Handling Components)**](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vGokwMXPQItZmTHZQbTO4qwj_SQymFhRS_nJmiH0K3w/edit) here.

> One module that imports all component classes, no individual modules
>   for each component
>       components/
>       components.module.ts (ComponentsModule)
>       imports and exports all components the user creates
>
> ```
> component1/
>    component1.ts
>    component1.html
>
> component2/
>   component2.ts
>   component2.html
> ```
>
> Creating a page using generators automatically imports ComponentsModule

Hope above is very clear for you.You have to create your custom component inside the `components.module.ts`.When you create a page using CLI commands, it'll automatically import `ComponentsModule`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try and implement this later today and see how we go.

Comment: OK sure.If above solution will not work please share your code through Git repo (I know this is a sample app :) ). After that, we can play with it no.

Comment: I implemented as per your suggestion, and it seems to be working well. A single components.module.ts that `imports`, `declares` and `exports` each of the components, and then this single module is added to the `imports` of each page module that requires any of my custom components. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

I just wanted to add to @Sampath answer @Phillip Hartin comment with one key point.

If any of you components use any ionic tags i.e.  your components.module.ts will need to import  IonicModule aswell, my shared components module looks like this (note not called components.module.ts and not in components folder)

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { Component1 } from './component1/component1.component';
    import { Component2 } from './component2/component2.component';
    import { Component3 } from './component3/component3.component';

    @NgModule({
        declarations: [  
            Component1,  
            Component2,
            Component3
        ],
        imports: [
            IonicModule
        ],
        exports: [
            Component1,
            Component2,
            Component3
        ]
    })

    export class SharedModule { }
```