# Cannot load the custom component in my page

Tags: angular, ionic3

I want to import my custom component in one of my pages, but no chance so far. I generate the components using cli so they are in a single module (i.e. `ComponentsModule`) as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293644/ionic-3-ionicpage-can-t-use-bind-to-custom-components).
[image]

To make the matters worse, I can see that in VSCode if hold the `Ctrl` button on the custom tag, it shows the declaration of the component in a popup.
[image]

This is a very basic test component that I created and still no chance to even make this component to work.

**mypage.module.ts**

```
import { ComponentsModule } from '../../components/components.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TaskDetailsPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(DetailsPage),
    ComponentsModule
  ],
})
```

**test.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Generated class for the TestComponent component.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/api/core/Component for more info on Angular
 * Components.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: 'test.html'
})
export class TestComponent {

  text: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello TestComponent Component');
    this.text = 'Hello World';
  }

}
```

**components.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StarRatingViewerComponent } from './star-rating-viewer/star-rating-viewer';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test';



@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    StarRatingViewerComponent,
    TestComponent
   ],
    imports: [IonicModule],
    exports: [
    StarRatingViewerComponent,
    TestComponent
    ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

Am I missing something obvious? I have tried to exit the VSCode and launch again and all these sorts of funny tries but it's not working as expected yet.

**Edit:** error in text

> Template parse errors: 'test' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'test' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
>
> ```
>       [ERROR ->]<test></test>
>     </div>
>   </ion-item> "): ng:///AppModule/DetailsPage.html@60:10
> ```

Comment: can you please paste the error message as text and not image?

Comment: @SurajRao sure, added.

Comment: is `TaskDetailsPage` same as `DetailsPage`?

Comment: Also can you add the entire html where you are getting this error?

Comment: @SurajRao yes, they are the same. And the page is really simple. I have tested with very basic contents (almost the default contents when you create the page with cli)  but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have 2 different names for the same page.
I am referring to the page module where you are importing common.module.ts

```
import { ComponentsModule } from '../../components/components.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TaskDetailsPage,//here
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(DetailsPage),//and here
    ComponentsModule
  ],
})
```

The TaskDetailsPage in declaration array and DetailsPage in  IonicPageModule.forChild should be the same page name.